# Error sending data from raspberry pi 3 to xampp database?

Tags: xampp, raspberry-pi3

I have connected my [Raspberry Pi 3](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/) to my PC and running [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) in my laptop (Windows OS). I am trying to send data from raspberry pi to Xampp database using the laptop's IP address (`192.168.1.11`)

But every time I try to connect to the server, I get `"Error Connecting to server"`

Do I need to pre-configure anything?

Not sure where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I was using WLAN network in raspberry pi with a diff IP network of 10.163.14.xx and WiFi in Laptop with a IP of 192.168.xx.xx range.. That's the reason i couldn't send data, now i have connected my laptop also using the WLAN, so its WORKING... Thank u all....

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to access the database through a php file. You would need to create a virtualhost for that directory where your files are, and expose a port in order to be able to access it from your local network.

**Edit:**

Let's say your directory where your php file is is: C:/xampp/htdocs/mydir, and the port you want to expose is 3000

You would edit the httpd-vhosts.conf in your xampp/apache/conf/extra folder. and restart the apache service.

```
<VirtualHost *:3000>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mydir"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am sending using the urllib library from raspi and receiving the data using php.  Could you plz explain in detail on how to create a virtual host and all??

Comment: Edited the answer, now you should be able to access it through `192.168.1.11:3000`

Comment: This is my httpd-vhosts.conf file

Comment: This is my httpd-vhosts.conf file                            
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "G:/xampp/htdocs/pipark/server"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>
       Have I edited it correctly?? Stil the same error

Comment: You need to remove the `##`-s from the beginning of the lines. Thats the same thing if you would comment every line of php with `//` in your code. And also I think for this you don't need servername and serveralias.
And make a new virtualhost those that are commented are just for you to see how to make one, not to edit them. And also if you want to have it for example on port 3000 then you need to change the *:80 to *:3000, and then you should be able to access it from `192.168.1.11:3000`. And restart apache after edit.

Comment: Thanks for yr reply,